# Failed to mount folders in Linux guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vagrant, share

Until I reinstalled my Virtual Box and Vagrant, everything worked properly.

Now, `config.vm.synced_folder "source/tk_dev/src/repo/app", "/home/vagrant/www/tk_dev/app"` in my Vagrantfile leads to the following when typing `vagrant up`:

```
C:\Vagrant\box_website>vagrant up
[default] Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
your host and reload your VM.

Guest Additions Version: 4.0.4
VirtualBox Version: 4.3
[default] Setting hostname...
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /home/vagrant/www/tk_dev/src/repo/app
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually beacuse
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3`
/home/vagrant/www/tk_dev/src/repo/app /home/vagrant/www/tk_dev/src/repo/app
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` /home/vagrant/www/tk_
dev/src/repo/app /home/vagrant/www/tk_dev/src/repo/app
```

Unfortunately, I have not found any solution yet. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try reading those messages?

Comment: I got it, please see my answer. To the one who voted down my question: Please state a reason for to help me to improve my posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for my problem. I had a symbolic link on my Windows machine, which pointed from my repository into the shared directory. After deleting the symbolic link, it worked. It seems that using symbolic links is quite difficuilt not only on the Linux machine but also on the machine Virtual Box is running on.